# Can backlinks from ebook previews boost domain authority?

Tags: seo, backlinks, ebooks

I got an offer to contribute as an author to a book, which will be in printed and ebook version.

I am wondering if I can increase domain authority of my website, if there is a link to my personal site in the ebook. I think I can get some backlinks from ebook previews, but I am not sure if it can improve domain authority of my website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an ebook it will not be a valuable backlink for SEO (It'll not increase ranking, authority, etc..), but can be beneficial for your image and online reputation.

For the previews :
Google can crawl pdfs so it does count as a link however it's not the strongest link in the world.. Same for any ebook previews when the MIME type is a pdf, html, txt etc.. (Anything google can crawl)